# A way to do RSA "encryption" of padded SHA256 hash using command line openssl

Tags: openssl, rsa, encryption, bignum

I'm trying to come up with a one-liner solution using openssl, that will take in padded SHA256 digest of a message (256 bytes in this case, for RSA2048), and apply RSA "decryption" to the 256 byte digest, ie

```
m^d mod n
```

where n is the modulus, d is the private exponent and m is the digest message (padded). This is something that normally happens in normal RSA2048 authentication, but I need to do it piecemeal.

I tried this and it didn't work.

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -in msg.sha256 -inkey secret.pem -out msg.sha256.sig
RSA operation error
2675740:error:04065084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data too large for
modulus:rsa_eay.c:532:
```

In the hopes I am confusing encrypting and decryption (since I want to use a private exponent in the calculation) I tried this too

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -in msg.sha256 -inkey secret.pem -out msg.sha256.sig
RSA operation error
2675740:error:0406D06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_type_2:data too large
for key size:rsa_pk1.c:151:
```

Reading up on RSA "encryption/decryption", in this case I think I'm confusing file encryption/decryption with single message encryption/decryption. File encryption apparently is a higher level protocol that involves AES128 and all that. I don't want that, I just want to do the modular exponentiation with the private expononent.

I also tried `pkeyutil` (which I understand is the preferred method with the same results).  I'm pretty sure I'm going down the wrong path, and perhaps this is impossible from the command line (I know it's doable from the C API using "bignum".)

--- update ----

I tried removing the PKCS1 v1.5 padding from the SHA256 hash (so I am left with just the 32 bytes of hash), and passing that through, but that didn't work either.

```
$ head -32c msg.sha256 | openssl.exe rsautl -decrypt -inkey secret.pem -out test.sig
RSA operation error
2675740:error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is
 not 02:rsa_pk1.c:190:
2675740:error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed
:rsa_eay.c:616:
```

I tried the same with `-raw` and it completed without error, but the result was not what I expected (which I would expect, because it doesn't have the PKCS1v1.5 padding). Then I tried reversing the byte order of the input file, because openssl seems to be complaining about the fact that the input file (as a 256 byte BIGNUM) is slightly bigger than the modulus (as a 256 byte BIGNUM) and if you reverse the order of bytes, then the trailing 0 becomes a leading zero, and it is smaller. It completes, but the result is still not correct.

```
$ perl -e '$a = `cat msg.sha256`; print "".reverse($a);' > msg.sha256r

$ head -256c msg.sha256r | openssl.exe rsautl -encrypt -raw -inkey secret.pem -out test3e.sig
$ head -256c msg.sha256r | openssl.exe rsautl -decrypt -raw -inkey secret.pem -out test3d.sig
```

Yes, I realize I am just stumbling around in the dark, but you'd be surprised how many times I get lucky this way...

Both test3e.sig and test3d.sig do not agree with my calculation from a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 3):

The error you get, `data too large for modulus`, is because you entered the second `if` of the following code:

```
/* make data into a big number */
if (BN_bin2bn(from,(int)flen,f) == NULL) goto err;

if (BN_ucmp(f, rsa->n) >= 0)
    {
    RSAerr(RSA_F_RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT,RSA_R_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_MODULUS);
    goto err;
    }
```

`BN_bin2bn` converts your data `from`(unsigned char*) to bignum `f`(BIGNUM).
`BN_ucmp` then compares the bignums `f` and modulus `n`. `>=0` means `f>=n`.

Since your input is a SHA256 digest (256-byte, 2048 bit), the value of the converted digest can be larger than a 2048-bit modulus `n`, hence the error occurs.

It seems doable if you can modify your message to a shorter one. Also the function you're calling does padding after it calculates `f^d mod n` as the following line

```
if (!rsa->meth->bn_mod_exp(ret,f,d,rsa->n,ctx,
            rsa->_method_mod_n))
```

You may want to switch to `RSA_NO_PADDING` mode to get an expected answer.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I sent it only 32 bytes and let it try to pad it with PKCS1v1.5 padding, but it is still complaining.

Comment: I really should just give this question a rest, but now I am curious, as I am beginner in cryptography. If `f < n` is a requirement, then is this served by the particular choice of PKCS padding most significant bits (which are 0x0001FFFF .... down to SHA256)? If the openssl tool is complaining that the padded 2048 bits is "too big", then it must be reading my file as big-endian instead of little-endian. But I tried that, and while it didn't complain, it gave the wrong answer.

Comment: I don't think padding is the reason for getting wrong answers. And the decrypt function is reading your file as big-endian says [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html). I tried to get the result you want but the answers were incorrect. I'm guessing it's because "rsa_blinding" is turned on; otherwise `if (!rsa->meth->rsa_mod_exp(ret, f, rsa, ctx)) goto err;` should give correct answer. You are using a tool that's too powerful for your purpose,  leading us to this mess:P Try GMP.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try using the `-raw` parameter. If the message is already padded to the correct size, then you don't want the utility to try and pad it. It assumes `-pkcs` (PKCS 1.5) by default, which would explain why you get a "too large" error.

Comment: `-raw` gave the same results (too large).